# Flutter StateError (Bad state: No element)

Tags: flutter

I receive this error:

```
StateError (Bad state: No element)
```

surely there is to add a null check perhaps with orElse but I did not understand how to do it.

This is My code:

```
class RangeSmallPink {
  final int a;
  final int b;

  const RangeSmallPink(this.a, this.b);
  bool includes(int value) => value >= a && value <= b;
}


const xRangesSmallPink = [
  RangeSmallPink(10, 15),
  RangeSmallPink(16, 20),
  RangeSmallPink(21, 25),
  RangeSmallPink(26, 30),
  RangeSmallPink(31, 35),
  RangeSmallPink(36, 40),
  RangeSmallPink(41, 45),
  RangeSmallPink(46, 50)
];

int getIndexSmallPink(int value, List<RangeSmallPink> ranges) {
  return ranges.indexOf(ranges.firstWhere((range) => range.includes(value)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ranges.firstWhere((range)` may throw a StateError if no element is found found.

> If no element satisfies test, the result of invoking the orElse
> function is returned. If orElse is omitted, it defaults to throwing a **StateError**.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

Make sure that it is possible to find an element that satisfies the condition.